# apt-get install default-jre in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install default-jre
```

when I run `docker build -t myuser/test .', it generate:

"The command '/bin/sh -c ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install default-jre' returned a non-zero code: 1"

When I remove this command from Dockerfile `RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install default-jre`. Everything runs fine. I then connect to container via CLI and execute `apt-get install default-jre` and it works fine as well.

What is wrong with including `default-jre` into Dockerfile?

P.S.I am trying it all locally on Windows machine

P.P.S. It all originated from attempt to install `install.packages('rJava')` in R container

Here is full log just in case:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0.4
 ---> cb2456ad0c32
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y
 ---> Running in 96972e16d498
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Removing intermediate container 96972e16d498
 ---> ed9c451eab61
Step 3/3 : RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install default-jre
 ---> Running in adfebedd792c
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core ca-certificates-java dbus
  default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libapparmor1 libasound2
  libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libdbus-1-3
  libfontenc1 libgif7 libice6 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3 libpcsclite1 libsm6
  libxaw7 libxcb-shape0 libxcomposite1 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1
  libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless x11-common x11-utils
Suggested packages:
  default-dbus-session-bus | dbus-session-bus libasound2-plugins alsa-utils
  cups-common liblcms2-utils pcscd libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
  mesa-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf at-spi2-core ca-certificates-java dbus
  default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libapparmor1
  libasound2 libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2 libdbus-1-3
  libfontenc1 libgif7 libice6 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3 libpcsclite1 libsm6
  libxaw7 libxcb-shape0 libxcomposite1 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1
  libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless x11-common x11-utils
0 upgraded, 49 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
Need to get 43.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 193 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install default-jre' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You might be able to make it work by separating out the environment variable part. Just put `ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y` on the line before `RUN apt-get install default-jre`.

Comment: @Locke, thank you it worked! My actual Dockerfile is a bit longer. Do I need to use `ENV` in front of every `RUN` command?

Comment: The way I understand it, `ENV xxx=yyy` is more or less equivalent to you running `export xxx=yyy` so it should still be present for the remainder of the dockerfile. I think you can just put all your environment variable stuff at the top of the dockerfile and it should still work.

Comment: @Locke. I noticed that the following command would run without `ENV`: `RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17`. Do you have any guesses why ?

Comment: `VAR=value command argument` is standard Bourne shell syntax for setting an environment variable for a single command.  There are potential problems if you run `apt-get install` and `apt-get update` on separate lines and you might try combining them.  "Returned a non-zero exit code" just means "it didn't work"; can you [edit] the question to include the complete error message from the build?

Comment: @DavidMaze, just added it